# how to include multiple layout in single xml file and use in single activity

Tags: android, android-activity

I had the api response code which has 20 datas, in which 10 data is displayed in one layout1 and 5 data need to display in another layout2 using next button click in layout1 and 5 data need to display in another layout3 using next button. these all need to be happen in single activity.

I am new in android, please tell the functions or useful links.

Comment: try this link https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask.

Comment: @IbrahimAli thanks

Comment: What you need to do is create a pojo class called model, generate Getter & Setter, set value in model, make model parcelable, access where you want.

Comment: @AkshayKatariya yes i'm using teh getter setter method. but how to use that values in next screen on button click in same activity

Comment: put you code, so that i can understand what you wanted to do.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Model Class of the response to store the data. Then user ViewPager OR Fragments in one activity to show the data.

Here is an example of Model Class with demo response:

```
{
  "businesses": [
    {
      "id": "yelp-tropisueno",
      "name" : "Tropisueno",
      "display_phone": "+1-415-908-3801",
      "image_url": "http://s3-media2.ak.yelpcdn.com/bphoto/7DIHu8a0AHhw-BffrDIxPA/ms.jpg"
    }
  ] 
}
```

Code of Model Class:

```
public class Business {
private String id;
private String name;
private String phone;
private String imageUrl;

public String getName() {
    return this.name;
}

public String getPhone() {
    return this.phone;
}

public String getImageUrl() {
    return this.imageUrl;
}
}
```

Here are the links which will be help you:

http://pojo.sodhanalibrary.com/Convert

https://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html

https://developer.android.com/training/animation/screen-slide.html